# SSH connection through SSH tunnel keeps closing

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a PI at home that creates an SSH tunnel to my VPS with autossh so I can access it from my VPS.

When I log in to my PI from my VPS the connection keeps closing (which makes it unusable). For example when I edit a file or even when I cd to another directory, the connection closes.

However if I ssh from my PI to my VPS, the ssh session keeps running and doesn't close.

I would like to have a reliable session from my VPS to my PI

Here is the command I use to connect to create the tunnel:

```
autossh -M 5233 -N -R 2514:localhost:22 vps -o "ServerAliveInterval 60" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -i /home/xbian/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and here is my ssh config on my PI
[sshd config](http://pastebin.com/b7KhNAx0)

Comment: Does the connection close while you're using it, or only when you're (briefly, perhaps) not using it. Approximately how long do you get from the time you connect until it closes on you?

Comment: When  I edit a file it closes, or even when I cd to a directory, so I would say it doesn't matter if I'm typing or not. I would say the connection lasts for 1 or 2 minutes, sometimes less than that.

Comment: I've added that to the question thank you :)

Comment: Are you ssh'ing through the tunnel? If so you'll need the ServerAliveInterval added to that connection as well. Just because the tunnel stays up doesn't mean the connections inside it will as well. Curious as my SSH session are defined with `-o ServerAliveInterval=60`(they stay up for days typically). Your docs/flavour/distro might be different however.

Comment: I tried with this option and I have the same problem

Comment: I found the ```-M``` option of autossh to be unreliable and always use ```-M 0``` and let SSH do the connection monitoring (with ```TCPKeepAlive yes``` (or "```no```" for interactive connections) and ```ServerAliveInterval=30```).

Comment: @ckujau  Seems like setting -M 0 fixes the problem. Can you put your suggestion in an answer so I can select it as a solution :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `-M` option of autossh to be unreliable and always use `-M 0` and let SSH do the connection monitoring, along with [TCPKeepAlive=yes](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/ssh_config.5) (resp. "`no`" for interactive connections) and `ServerAliveInterval=30`.